# Unwrapping responses on WCF with XmlSerializer and Soap with RPC Literal

Tags: xml, wcf, soap, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I´m trying to consume a Soap 1.1 web service with WCF. After generating proxies with svcutil from wsdl definition, I found that the all the responses where null.

It seems that the service uses RPC Literal so WCF fallbacks to using `XmlSerializer`. Here is the wsdl definition:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:typens="http://www.myservice.es/Schemas" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://www.myservice.es/Schemas">

<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.myservice.es/Schemas">
        <xsd:include schemaLocation="../xsd/myservicetypes.xsd"/>           
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<message name="serviceRequest"/>
<message name="serviceResponse">
    <part name="serviceReturn" type="typens:DateTimeResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="QueryServiceDateTimePort">
    <operation name="QueryServiceDateTime">
        <input message="typens:serviceRequest"/>
        <output message="typens:serviceResponse"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="QueryServiceDateTimeBinding" type="typens:QueryServiceDateTimePort">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="QueryServiceDateTime">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:QueryServiceDateTime"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://www.myservice.es/Schemas"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://www.myservice.es/Schemas"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="QueryServiceDateTimeService">
    <port name="QueryServiceDateTimePort" binding="typens:QueryServiceDateTimeBinding">
        <soap:address location="https://www.tests.com"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

However, the service returns this response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <serviceResponse>
         <serviceReturn>
            <DateTime v="2013-04-20T01:13:22.001" xmlns="http://www.myservice.es/Schemas"/>
         </serviceReturn>
      </serviceResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Both WCF and SoapUI expect and element named `QueryServiceDateTimeResponse` instead or before `serviceResponse`, so they fail to deserialize or validate the response.

How can I make WCF reconice this response and deserialize it? Can I mark the proxies anyway to unwrap that element?

I should note that I can't use MessageContract in this scenario as is incompatible with RPC - Literal.

Answer (score 0):

As i found in this post ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996466.aspx), you probably can switch to document - literal.

Comment: When I switch to document - literal, the service returns 404, as it does not understand de request message.